# Css media query for safari (only) targeting iPad and lower

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, safari, media-queries

There are several other posts asking for a similar solution, but I haven't been able to get any of the posted answers to work for us. We need to target Safari on iPhone and iPad

```
/* Safari 7.1+ */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .hero-section {
    sa-search-nav ion-row {
    background: none;
  }

  .search-form {
    ion-col.select {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
  }
}

  form.search-form {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No magic here, CSS media queries are not too powerful yet, to accomplish what you want. Any device that has a maximum width of 768px will obey the same CSS rule.

I think what you need here is a hack:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {

  // Safari 6.2,7.1+
  _::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root {

    .hero-section {
      sa-search-nav ion-row {
        background: none;
      }

      .search-form {
        ion-col.select {
          margin-top: 0px;
          margin-left: 0px;
        }
      }
    }

    form.search-form {
      min-height: 300px;
    }

  }
}
```

Even this, however, will not ensure that this code will only run on mobile devices. Note that the above code is SCSS, not CSS. I believe yours, was too. Please give it a try and let me know. Courtesy of [Jeff Clayton](https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html).